# Bootstrap modal demo example doesn't work on localhost but works on live environment

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I am testing out the bootstrap modal function using the bootstrap official documentation. I have copied the exact code from their website. Things I have tested:

- Checking in the browser if js,jquery and css files src location is correct
- Made a brand new file and only imported things that are needed for modal to work to make sure my own .css or js files are not interfering with this.
- Tested this on chrome, ie and firefox inc. private browsing - Still same. It just displays the button link and when you click on it it doesn't popup anything.
- Checking the console for any error logs. No errors.

I am kind of mind-blown what could cause this? Is there possible that some kind of server-side (using xampp v3.2.2 and running on port :8080) could cause this not to work?
 - Since stackoverflow required some sort of code in here I included the head

Here is my full code: http://jsfiddle.net/bLajz5ud/

```
 <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">

      <title></title>
    </head>
```

Comment: Try opening the modal using [`.modal('toggle')`](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/modal/#via-javascript) instead

Comment: The code provided in the jsfiddle works fine...

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you have an active internet connection. Jquery is included using a CDN URL

> script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"

if you don't have active internet connection, no jquery code would run